# Email Templates Testing

Tags: html, css, email-templates

Is there a free service that i can use to test my email templates (html and css) for various email services like (outlook, gmail, hotmail and so on)?

I built email templates, but I need to test them on various email accounts.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, just send an email to whatever "service" or real email client you want to test with...

Comment: Yes one services is free http://testi.at/ not all client support but work pretty well

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any free services like that, but there are two very good services: https://litmus.com/ and https://www.emailonacid.com/
Both of them have free trial versions, so you can evaluate them.

Also, you can create your email templates with EDMdesigner. (https://app.edmdesigner.com) The templates created with this tool are compatible with most of the existing email clients. http://edmdesigner.com/compatibility